SQLAlchemy: to_sql create empty table after inspect
I have strange behavior here. After I init inspect(cn), to_sql writes an empty table to the database.
 def save_data_to_sql(df, table_name, cn):

    df.to_sql(con=cn, name='test_1', if_exists='replace', index=False) << Table with data

    # Check if the table exists
    inspector = inspect(cn)
    if inspector.has_table(table_name):
        logger.info(f"Table exists")
    else:
        logger.info(f"Table does not exist")

    
    df.to_sql(con=cn, name='test_2', if_exists='replace', index=False) << Empty table?!?!

Someone an idea what's wrong?

The relation between table_name and test_1/test_2 is vague.

The issue was how I created the connection to MariaDB. So this one works:
def crcn():
    """Create and return a database connection with SQLAlchemy."""

    try:
        engine = create_engine(
            f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB_CONFIG['user']}:{DB_CONFIG['password']}@{DB_CONFIG['host']}/{DB_CONFIG['database']}",
            connect_args={
                "charset": "utf8mb4",
                "collation": "utf8mb4_general_ci"
            }
        )
        print("Connected to MariaDB using SQLAlchemy")
        return engine

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None

